# Using DBI in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dbi

I'm using Rails 3.0.0.rc and have installed the 'dbi' gem inside my gemfile and ran bundle install. But when I do the following require, it returns an error of 'no such file to load -- dbi'

```
require 'dbi'
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I using the wrong gem? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to require the gem once it's in your Gemfile.